# Is my translation correct? If not, please correct me

Tags: translation

I wanted to translate this into Chinese but I don't know if my translation is correct. Please make the necessary corrections if needed. It's a poem.

> Relationships, of all kinds, are like sand held in your hand. Held loosely, with an open hand, the sand remains where it is. The minute you close your hand and squeeze tightly to hold on, the sand trickles through your fingers. You may hold on to some of it, but most will be spilled. A relationship is like that. Held loosely, with respect and freedom for the other person, it is likely to remain intact. But hold too tightly, too possessively, and the relationship slips away and its lost.

My translation:

> 各种关系就像手中的沙子一样。松散地举起，张开手，砂仍然在那里。当你闭上你的手紧紧握住时，沙子就会通过你的手指流下。你可以坚持一些，但大多数会被泄漏。关系就是这样。松散地举行，尊重和自由的对方，它可能保持完好。但是，也要坚持得过于紧张，这种关系就会消失，失去了。

Comment: 2 alternative suggestions 1。保持一些在手里，2。对（向）对方尊重和自由，

Comment: what? where would i put this sentences you typed?

Comment: where they fit in, i.e. the sections that contain 一些 and 尊重 respectively, 1. could replace part of 你可以坚持一些 2. part of 尊重和自由的对方

Comment: can you just retype the entire sentence then post it?

Comment: ???  你可以坚持一些  -> 你可以保持一些在手里,  尊重和自由的对方->对（向）对方尊重和自由

Answer (score 1):

> *Relationships, of all kinds, are like sand held in your hand.*
>
> *各种关系就像手中的沙子一样。*
>
> '关系' in Chinese does not automatically imply 'relationship between people' you have to spell it out like '人与人的关系'

**人与人的关系就像手中的沙子一样**

> Held loosely, with an open hand, the sand remains where it is.
>
> 松散地举起，张开手，砂仍然在那里。
>
> No problem here

**松散地举起，张开手，砂仍然在那里。**

> *The minute you close your hand and squeeze tightly to hold on, the sand trickles through your fingers.*
>
> *当你闭上你的手紧紧握住时，沙子就会通过你的手指流下。*
>
> 通过你的手指 could mean through your fingers like bullet goes through a wall, better make it clear that it is 'between your fingers  '从你的手指之间'

**当你闭上你的手紧紧握住时，沙子就会从你的手指之间流下。**

> *You may hold on to some of it, but most will be spilled.*
>
> *你可以坚持一些，但大多数会被泄漏*
>
> 'hold on to' here means 'to keep' not ' to persist' therefore, the Chinese translation should be '保留' not '坚持'
>
> '一些' means 'some' , but It can be mistaken for an adverb (a little) for '坚持'  I think '一小部分'(a small part) sound better
>
> 泄漏 mainly means 'leak' (of information), It is better to use '溜走' (slip away)

**你可以保留一小部分，但大多数会溜走**

> *A relationship is like that. Held loosely, with respect and freedom for the other person, it is likely to remain intact.*
>
> *关系就是这样。松散地举行，尊重和自由的对方，它可能保持完好*
>
> 举行 mainly means 'to hold' (an event) , it is better to use '维持'(maintain)
>
> 尊重 is a verb, 自由 is a noun. '尊重和自由的对方' should be changed to '尊重和给予对方自由'
>
> 尊重 along as a clause has only one word, and is very odd as an expression. Meanwhile, it can mean *respect loosely* because it is immediately after 松散地维持
>
> A dash or a comma is more appropriate in this context, as the two sentences belong to one group (意群)
>
> the original sentence features the three aspects as the conditions for intact relationships. 便能 can reflect this as it include a implicit meaning of *thus*. 就能 serves as *thus* as well, but too explicit.

**人与人的关系就是这样——松散地维持，相互尊重，并给予对方自由，它便能保持完好**

> *But hold too tightly, too possessively, and the relationship slips away and its lost.*
>
> *但是，也要坚持得过于紧张，这种关系就会消失，失去了。*
>
> 也要 means 'also' ; 'too' in 'too tightly' is '太'

**但是，太坚持，太紧张，人際关系就会一一消失而去**

*It is your work, I don't want to rewrite it for you. Therefore I only  make corrections  that's absolutely necessary*

Comment: yeah but my Chinese aint so great i dont know where to put the neccesarry corrections .pls help

Comment: Just compare your translation with my edition in bold text